# VBA: Subtracting a cell from an active cell value

Tags: excel, vba, subtraction

I have this solution, but i would like to print a formula for it.

```
Sub Minus()

    ActiveCell = ActiveCell - ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) 

End Sub
```

This code returns only correct value, but i would like full original value minus adjacent cell.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
Sub Minus()

    With ActiveCell
        .Formula = "=" & .Value & "-" & .Offset(0, -1).Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I had a problem with &, but changing .formula to .formulaLocal solved the problem. decimals were getting in the way.  Thank you for you help!